# Mysqld don't start, and don't log

Tags: server, mysql, log

`mysqld` don't start, as there are no process, and no logs.

`SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)`

Running `mysqld start`  (as root)

`151025 14:52:07 [Warning] Using unique option prefix key_buffer instead of key_buffer_size is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use the full name instead.
151025 14:52:07 [Note] mysqld (mysqld 5.5.44-0ubuntu0.14.04.1) starting as process 1652 ...`

And with `--verbose` it's return the same.

Of course, I check the logs, but there are no logs.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are some of the solutions for this problem.

Maybe `/var/run/mysql/mysql.sock` is missing. If `/var/run/mysql/mysql.sock` is missing you can replace it by doing the following:

```
sudo touch /var/run/mysql/mysql.sock
sudo chown mysql /var/run/mysql/mysql.sock
```

If this doesn't help you can try and reinstall it.

First remove it:

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove mysql-server
sudo apt-get --purge remove mysql-client
sudo apt-get --purge remove mysql-common

sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get autoclean
```

Also remove MySQL dir:

```
sudo rm -rf /etc/mysql
```

And then install it:

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server mysql-client
```

After that you can check status:

```
sudo service mysql status
```

Workaround if AppArmor is the problem:

```
sudo aa-complain /etc/apparmor.d/*mysql*
```

And also check if there is enough drive space.

Comment: Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer. However, if I delete my DB, I will lost all files.

Comment: You can also try `mysql.server start` if your server is not running.

Comment: Or maybe you need to install  `mysql-server` if you installed `mysql-client` only.

Comment: Keep trying and give me feedback on your process because this problem can be solved in many ways and some of these solutions must work for you.

Comment: Another command to use after installing `mysql-server` would be `sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start`.

Comment: Sometimes `sudo /etc/init.d/mysql restart` command can reveal the issue so try and run that also.

Comment: `mysql.server start` -> command not found | `sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start` -> `fail` | `[ok]` then `[fail]` | no clue, nothing about errors.

Comment: Maybe it's a permissions problem. It should be owned by  `mysql` and not by `root`. Try to check that and change if this is the case. Here is the link about that http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=801607. Reviewing posts there might be helpful.

Comment: Have you tried some of the solutions given in the answer above?

Comment: Check also this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11990708/error-cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-var-run-mysqld-mysq. Hope it helps.

Comment: Can you give a way to change the ownership of these file to `mysql`? And yes I tried your solutions, but it's not working.

Comment: To change permission to `mysql` folder `sudo chmod -R 755 /var/lib/mysql/`

Comment: Run this to check status `mysqladmin -u root -p status`

Comment: You can also try this. Edit `sudo gksu gedit /etc/mysql/my.cnf` and modify `#bind-address       = 127.0.0.1` to `bind-address        = localhost` and then restart `sudo /etc/init.d/mysql restart`

Comment: It was the `bind-adress`! Thank you so much. Stupid from my part.